# PHP error_reporting(E_ERROR); still shows E_DEPRECATED in PHP 8.1

Tags: php, command-line-interface, strftime, php-8.1

PHP on command line shows E_DEPRECATED even when error_reporting() has been set to only report E_ERROR.

I have this dummy code:

```
$prev_level = error_reporting(E_ERROR);
echo $prev_level."\n";
echo error_reporting()."\n";
echo strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time());
```

which outputs:

```
32767 
1 
E_DEPRECATED: Function strftime() is deprecated in .......... 
2024-03-06
```

However, if I completely turn it off with `error_reporting(0);`, the E_DEPRECATED doesn't show.

My php.ini settings related to errors are:

```
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => syslog => syslog
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
log_errors => On => On
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug they fixe? I can't reproduce it in 8.2.

Comment: Can't reproduce in 8.1.0 at https://3v4l.org/KcerY#v8.1.0 either

Comment: I don't think you can test with a online sandbox since they have their own error_reporting settings. 
Any chance you can make a raw PHP script and run it?

Comment: I guess you are using a custom error handler.

Comment: My 8.2 test was in a `php -a` session running on our own Linux server. I don't have an 8.1 instance handy. Also, when I changed to `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_DEPRECATED)` in the online tester, the deprecation warning appeared, so I don't think they're doing anything funny with errors.